# How can i show buttons next to each other?

Tags: css

i am using some buttons 
and i want to list them in one line. i tried this

```
.myclass{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

but i didnt work..

Comment: @DannyBeckett i tried some things but they didnt work. Next time i'll keep it mind to post my efforts. thx you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the buttons a `float: left;` after your float you have to set the next element `clear: both;` now you buttons should be in one line.

If the animation destroys your layout give the buttons a with.

Comment: how i define the next element? can you post me the code plz?

Comment: I post you a [css tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). If you wanna use it lean it.

Comment: you could just post the tutorial and dont play it smart..

Comment: Alternatively instead of putting `clear` on the next element, you can use [`clearfix` like this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on the element containing the buttons, then they can be put anywhere regardless of what the next element is.

Comment: @yaylitzis click the 'css tutorial' the link is wrapped in ....

Comment: @Silom I saw it and thank you. Before i meant that it was not necessairy to make your self smart to someone that is learning now css.. i am reading the tutorial and ill find the solution to my problem..

Comment: I would like to help you, if you have more questions just write me. I can remember leaning it and I can tell you from my experience it is impotent to get the logic of css with html ... how it work together. And after you know that, you can lean programming languages. This is a normal process of leaning and walk throw it is well. :) as I said write if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table with a single row. See [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478901/So-You-Want-To-Line-Up-Link-Buttons-Huh) for an example.